# Keep getting Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I am trying out my code for updating and showing it to the user. Basically it is able to do what I need to do but after performing it I get this error

> C:\Users\tester01_2\myproject\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:174
>         throw err;
>         ^
>       Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:357:11)
>       at ServerResponse.header ( 
>       C:\Users\tester01_2\myproject\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:725:10)
>       at ServerResponse.send 
>       (C:\Users\tester01_2\myproject\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
>       at C:\Users\tester01_2\myproject\dbUpdate.js:13:14
>       at C:\Users\tester01_2\myproject\dbUpdate.js:28:5
>       at handleCallback (C:\Users\tester01_2\myproject\node_modules\mongodb-
>       core\lib\cursor.js:171:5)
>       at nextFunction (C:\Users\tester01_2\myproject\node_modules\mongodb-
>       core\lib\cursor.js:682:5)
>       at Cursor.next [as _next] 
>       (C:\Users\tester01_2\myproject\node_modules\mongodb-
>       core\lib\cursor.js:692:3)
>       at loop 
>       (C:\Users\tester01_2\myproject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:694:8)
>       at _each 
>       (C:\Users\tester01_2\myproject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:741:16)

**This is my code**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';

module.exports = {

postCollection : function(req, res){
    var issueQty = req.body.issueQty;
    var itemDescrip = req.body.itemDescrip;
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    updateRecord(db, req, function(doc) {
    return res.send('Record Found. Now updating this document...' + 
itemDescrip + ' Record Updated. This is the new record ' + doc )
    res.end();
    db.close();
    });

});
}
}
var updateRecord = function(db, req, callback) {
var cursor = db.collection('documents').find({'Item Description': 
req.body.itemDescrip, 'Issued QTY': req.body.issueQty})
cursor.each(function(err,doc){
   assert.equal(err, null);
     if(doc != err){
         console.log('Successfully queried');
         console.log(doc);
         callback(JSON.stringify(doc));

     } else{
         throw err;
     }
  });
db.collection('documents').updateMany(
  { 'Item Description': req.body.itemDescrip},
  {
    $set: { 'Issued QTY': req.body.issueQty }
  },function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
    console.log('Done');
    console.log(results);

});
};
```

I think it has to do with my res due to all the threads I have seen being res being in a wrong position but I need to put my `res.send` there so that it can use `doc`. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should remove `return` in front of `res.send()`.

Secondly, in `updateRecord` function, the `callback` function shouldn't be called in a loop, it will execute multiple times. And you close the db before you execute `updateMany`.

If you want to send doc, you should use a temp array to hold the doc, and pass it to res when you finish all logics in updateRecord.

If I understand you correctly, following is my modification of your codes,

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';

var updateRecord = function(db, req, callback) {
    db.collection('documents').updateMany({ 'Item Description': req.body.itemDescrip }, {
        $set: { 'Issued QTY': req.body.issueQty }
    }, function(err, results) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        console.log('Done');
        console.log(results);
        var cursor = db.collection('documents').find({
            'Item Description': req.body.itemDescrip,
            'Issued QTY': req.body.issueQty
        });
        var temp = [];
        cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }
            console.log('Successfully queried');
            console.log(doc);
            temp.push(JSON.stringify(doc));
        });
        callback(null, temp);
    });
};

module.exports = {
    postCollection: function(req, res) {
        var issueQty = req.body.issueQty;
        var itemDescrip = req.body.itemDescrip;
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if(err) {
              res.send(err);
              res.end();
              db.close();
              return;
            }
            updateRecord(db, req, function(err, docs) {
                if(err){
                  res.send(err);
                }
                else{
                  res.send(docs);
                }
                res.end();
                db.close();
            });

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @OngKongTat I updated my answer, you should check your updateRecord function twice.

Comment: Sorry I do not really get what you mean by loop, do you mean the function or for/while loop etc ? How do you know when to put db.close() because I am a bit confused.

Comment: @OngKongTat cursor.each is a loop, and your callback function is called before updateMany, so you call db.close before you call updateMany.

Comment: I am not able to pass the temp array with doc to res because doc will be undefined due to the fact that doc is declared in the function which is also in another function so I don't exactly know how should I adjust the function such that doc is able to be used in postCollection.

Comment: @OngKongTat I updated my answer, you can see if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Your code works in a sense that it does not give me the same error but it does not give an output. Which might be because I am testing it on postman for a web API so right now I would have to find a way to execute it asynchronously such that it does not do both at the same time.